# Plotting a Line from a known point to points in a fitted curve in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data whose points I have plotted and fitted using a power of 2 fit in MATLAB. I'm trying to draw 3 lines to that curve as tangential lines. Each of these lines start from the co-ordinates of say, (x,y): (2,0) (4,0) (9,0).

Is it possible for MATLAB to draw lines from the curve to the first known point until the line has only one solution (tangent to the curve) with the curve?

I feel that this requires some sort of specified interval which tells MATLAB to step the co-ordinates until it finds the closest point. Does anyone know if this has been done or can be done at all?

Comment: I may be wrong, but given fitted parameters _a,b,..._ for the curve _c_, can't you just solve directly for _min[c(a,b,...) - (x,y)]_? There are [several methods](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/optimization.html) for that.

Comment: Sure Matlab can do almost everything you want to do, but I do not understand exactly what you want. Maybe add the plot you already have, and add some lines with Paint or so of the lines you still want to add?

Answer (score 0):

From a point not lying on the curve, you want to draw a line that is tangent to it. In case of a convex function like y=2^x this is only possible from a point under the curve (not over it).

Since you already have the point (call it (a,b)), you need the slope of such a line. The slope is determined by the values (y-b)/(x-a) where (x,y) runs over the curve. Specifically, the "forward-looking" tangent has the slope equal to the minimum of (y-b)/(x-a) over all x>a. And the "backward-looking " tangent has the slope equal to the maximum of (y-b)/(x-a) over all x

Here is a very straightforward implementation of the above: I used `find` to restrict the search to either x>a or x<a and took `min` and `max` to find the slopes.

```
x = 0:0.01:4;
y = 2.^x;
a = 2; 
b = 3;
k = min((y(find(x>a))-b)./(x(find(x>a))-a));
plot(x,y)
hold on
plot(x,k*(x-a)+b,'r')
k = max((y(find(x<a))-b)./(x(find(x<a))-a));
plot(x,k*(x-a)+b,'g')
```

[image: tangents]